# Colour (color) flash during segue (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm fairly new to modern programming (the last serious experience I had was AMOS on my old Amiga!), but I've done my best to learn objective C with a view to developing an app (for iOS only at the moment).  I've got a (hopefully very simple) question which I've done my best to research already without any joy.

I've got the bulk of my relatively basic app laid down already.  From my home ViewController, I've got four options, all of which have colour-coded buttons, linked by segue to the content ViewControllers.

As a nice flourish, more than anything else, I'd like to make the whole screen flash briefly in the colour of the button pressed (this app is aimed at non-programmers, and a bit of theming will not only make things look good, but also hopefully aid orientation/ intuititivity.

So far I have tried:

- adding a new ViewController with a screen blank except for the themed colour and an automated custom segue controlled by NSTimer.  // This is sub-optimal as if the user wants to navigate back to the home page they have to jump through two pages rather than one, and if they're a bit slow then they may get stuck in a loop.
- dicking around with NSTimer and self.window.backgroundColor/ setBackgroundColor.  // both of these options end up with my app crashing - probably due to coding ineptitude!

Any ideas?  For example, if my user clicked the 'Emergency Guidelines' UIButton, then I would have the screen flash red (the chosen theme colour for this section) for a barely perceptibly but subconsciously awesome period before seamlessly transitioning the app to the relevant page.

Sorry if it's a bit of a noobish question.  I'm keen to hear any answers, even appropriately directed tough love.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different way. Don't use an extra viewController, instead add a colored UIView that covers the whole screen when the button was pressed. Animate a fade out, and once it's faded out completely remove that view and perform the push to the next viewController.

That's probably the easiest way, takes only this much code:

```
- (IBAction)demoButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIView *flashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    flashView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:flashView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.1 options:0 animations:^{
        flashView.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [flashView removeFromSuperview];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushDemo1" sender:sender];
    }];
}
```

Play around with `duration` and `delay` until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into core animation? it would help if you therw up some code but i thing Apple's Core Animation tutorial is pretty straight forward with how you can trigger animation effects especially if a button is pressed like you mentioned for your color flash idea. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html
you can also pull this up in X code which i suggest, or youtube some tutorials or github etc.
veritas